# Adding constraints to iminuit fitter

Tags: python, constraints, data-fitting, iminuit

I am trying to add a constraint to a very complicated minimization problem I have but I am not sure how to implement it, even after reading the docs.

I have a simple example that if answered will help me with my original problem. Here is the code:

```
from iminuit import Minuit
def f(x,y,z):
    return (x-1.)**2 +(y-2*x)**2 + (z-3.*x)**2 -1.

    m=Minuit(f, x=.5, error_x=0.2, limit_x=(0.,1.), y=0.,limit_y=
   (0.,1.), print_level=1)

m.migrad();
```

I would love to add a constraint, say x+y=1.

Thanks

Comment: I suppose if I constrain my x and y to the interval say (0,1) and just weight each variable by the factor 1/(x+y) it will work. It will work but is that not lame? What about more complicated constraints. I wonder if there are any constructs I don't know about with this particular fitter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my own question is don't bother using minuit. Use scipy.optimize with method SLSQP. It has equality and inequality constraint methods built in.